# Git cvsexportcommit and add new files

Tags: git, cvs

I don't know much about perl and I'm having troubles adding the functionality to git-cvsexportcommit.perl to add new files created on a git project when switching to cvs. I always get an error such as

```
cvs status: nothing known about `private/includes/suiviAnnuelpdf.php'
Huh? Status 'Unknown' reported for unexpected file 'no file suiviAnnuelpdf.php'
```

do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I believe that there is a bug in `git-cvsexportcommit`.  `Status 'Unknown'` and `'no file ...` shouldn't appear side by side.  The code that parses those lines is failing.

Comment: Specifically, I think that the line `push (@afiles,$1) if m/^ create mode [0-7]+ (.*)$/;` never matches anything...  Thus you end up with "Unknown" *and* "no file", when those should be mutually exclusive states.  In the comment above, 'those lines' should mean 'the output of git-apply' or 'the output of git-diff-tree'. (I can't tell which, I'm not a perl person.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if you found a solution but I've just been doing this and encountered a similar problem (mine was a file which I had deleted from CVS in a commit prior to a Git migration). The issue was I had not committed any changes into my Git repo so cvsexportcommit was attempting to replay the last change which was the deletion of this file. CVS complained it knew nothing about the file (too right I'd deleted it).

For future reference this is what I've just used to send a commit into CVS from a Git repo. You will need a CVS sandbox at the ready which I'll call `foo-CVS` and the git repo which I'll call `foo`.

```
cd /tmp
cvs co -d foo-CVS foo
git clone /my/foo.git
cd foo
<DO THE CHANGE on file.txt>
git add file.txt
git commit file.txt
git cvsexportcommit -w ../foo-CVS -v -u HEAD
cd ../foo-CVS
cvs commit -F .msg file.txt
```

The command can also do the commit for you as well but I feel better reading what changes are going into CVS for the moment until I trust the process totally.